# Possible integration over zero-form?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, path-integral, integration

This is referring to equation 3.5 in [Topology Change in (2+1)-Dimensional Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9406006). As you can see the ghost action derived after a quick Fadeev-Popov procedure yields an action, namely
$$I_{\text {ghost }}=-\int_{M}(\bar{f} \wedge * D * D f+\bar{g} \wedge * D * D g)$$

that seems to be an integration over zero-form in 3D. Now, it is known that only $m$-forms can be integrated in $m$-dimensions, it seems somehow the ghost action is incorrect mathematically. Maybe, the volume factor is implicit somehow. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken to one of the authors of the paper and he said that $\bar{f}$ and $\bar{g}$ are three-forms. They are basically auxiliary ghost-forms to encapsulate the FD determinant.